# Building a large (5000 elements +) 2 way binding / syncing front end with js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding, javascript-databinding

Im building a large 2 way syncing (read + write) spreadsheet front end (think google drive spreadsheet) for an application, the back end keeping all the data in sync between the users / views is fine, but i keep running into problems with the number of 2 way bindings on a page. Im currently using angualr.js and there seems to be limit of around 1500 elements, after that the js becomes un responsive.

Whats the normal approach for building large 2 way data binding / syncing on the front end ?

Comment: Are all 5000 on screen at the same time?

Comment: @PaulS. - no the user can scroll through the spreadsheet, so at any one time there will be around 20 rows and 10 columns actually in the part of the table they are looking at, but they can also scroll up / down, left / right to see more

Comment: `20 * 10 = 200 < 1500` so why not try using bindings only on the visible area/the region around the visible area, and add/remove them as the user navigates

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure services _Google_ does not use an independent sync for each item, but rather a single one for the whole document, where the updates get a reference designating which cell it is talking about